# Maemo, liblocation-dev/nokia-binaries: how can I get it?

Tags: gps, maemo, n900

I want to write a small GPS application on my Nokia N900, but I can't install liblocation-dev, because I need a token from the SDK EULA. Can't access this EULA's website (http://tablets-dev.nokia.com/eula/index.php). What should I do now? Thanks.